# How do I import function from .pyx file in python?

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to run Hadoopy, which has a file _main.pyx, and `import _main` is failing with module not found in __init__.py.

I'm trying to run this on OS X w/ standard python 2.7.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add this code before you try to import `_main`:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

Note that `pyximport` is part of [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), so you'll have to install that if it isn't already.

Comment: I don't have that module installed.  I downloaded some files from http://www.prescod.net/pyximport/, and then it says I need Pyrex.Distutils. Before I keep digging around for libraries, figured check to see if I'm missing something obvious (i.e. install cython or some other library/app/package)

Comment: @dolan: Yes, you'll need Cython. I assumed you already had it installed as your question was tagged with it.

Comment: To install Cython you have 3 options: 1. Run `pip install Cython` or 2. Goto http://cython.org., download it and run `python setup.py install` or 3. Run `pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"`

Comment: This still results in a `has no attribute {function name}` for me.  My `.pyx` is cythonized python from which I am able to get a `.so` and `.c` file.

Comment: hey @mLstudent33 , have you got the problem solved?

Answer (score 11):

You need to make sure you have followed all steps:

1. Install the Cython package using `pip`

   ```
   pip install Cython
   ```
2. Create a Cython file `bbox.pyx`

   ```
   cimport cython
   import numpy as np
   cimport numpy as np

   DTYPE = np.float32
   ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t

   @cython.boundscheck(False)
   def compare_bboxes(
          np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] boxes1,
          np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] boxes2):
    ...
   ```
3. Create `setup.py` **in the same directory**

   ```
   from distutils.core import setup, Extension
   from Cython.Build import cythonize
   import numpy

   package = Extension('bbox', ['bbox.pyx'], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
   setup(ext_modules=cythonize([package]))
   ```
4. Build the Cython

   ```
   python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
   ```
5. Create your main python script `run.py` **in the same directory**

   ```
   import pyximport
   pyximport.install(setup_args={"script_args" : ["--verbose"]})
   from bbox import compare_bboxes

   def main(args):
      boxes1 = args.boxes1
      boxes2 = args.boxes2
      result = compare_bboxes(boxes1, boxes2)
   ```
6. Run your main script **in the same directory**

   ```
   python run.py
   ```

Comment: nice answer; how to solve the case where the main script is not in the same directory of cython module? 
solved: add to main script: 
import pyximport 
pyximport.install()