# How to import .pyx files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i run `test.py` https://github.com/zisianw/FaceBoxes.PyTorch

It imports this file https://github.com/zisianw/FaceBoxes.PyTorch/blob/master/utils/nms_wrapper.py

And this file tries to import the two `.pyx` files inside this folder

https://github.com/zisianw/FaceBoxes.PyTorch/tree/master/utils/nms

How can I convert those `.pyx` files to normal Python code or just import them somehow?

I am getting this error without doing anything

```
from .nms.cpu_nms import cpu_nms, cpu_soft_nms
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.nms.cpu_nms'
```

Possible solution is not working.

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

It is giving me this error

```
 > ImportError: Building module utils.nms.cpu_nms failed: ["distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\\\2019\\\\Community\\\\VC\\\\Tools\\\\MSVC\\\\14.25.28610\\\\bin\\\\HostX86\\\\x64\\\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2\n"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import function from .pyx file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508803/how-do-i-import-function-from-pyx-file-in-python)

Comment: No sir @SwetankPoddar . I mentioned in my question. I get an error, when i try this solution

Comment: Do you have cpython installed?

Comment: `cl.exe` is the linker that links compiled code into an executable or library. Error 2 *usually* means that a file cannot be found.

Comment: Yes @SwetankPoddar

Comment: How can I just switch it back to Python?

Comment: Did you run make.sh?

Comment: No, let me try now. I use windows by the way.

Comment: Also, I will later convert this python program to a Pyinstaller exe file. So It would have been perfect, if i could change it to `.py` file. Is it possible?

Comment: The code inside `.pyx` looks similar to `.py` code with some changes

Comment: @Rahul you need to install pyximport as follows: `pyximport.install(setup_args={"script_args" : ["--verbose"]})` to see what is going wrong with the compiler options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before import, make sure FaceBoxes and Sim3DR are built successfully, e.g.,

```
sh build.sh
```