# Is it possible to include .pyx in a file.py

Tags: python, cython

I had a function in python which was 3 for loops to do some calculations. It was very slow so I looked for solutions to speed up my Python code and I saw Cython was a way to accelerate Python code. I wrote my Cython function in a notebook and it was working great so I wanted to include it to my existing project but now I can not import this function in other file to be called. I tried to do this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508803/how-do-i-import-function-from-pyx-file-in-python):

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
from my module import function_a, function_b
```

but it still gives me the following error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'

I'm running Python 3.8.3 and Cython 0.29.21

My folder structure is the following

## Folder

- my_module.pyx
- where_I_want_to_call.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## File structure:

```
PS C:\Users\adeee\Desktop\test> tree /F
C:.
    ip.pyx
    test.py
```

So you can see that I have my main `test.py` file which I run. I also have an `ip.pyx` file from which I import `check_ip` function.

Maybe you have some kind of typo in your code. I can see that you have

> `from my module import function_a, function_b`

but you should have:

> `from my_module import function_a, function_b`

It is important to include the `_` sign.

## Code:

#### test.py

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import ip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip.check_ip('192.168.1.1')
```

#### ip.pyx

```
import ipaddress

def check_ip(user_ip):
    try:
        ip = ipaddress.ip_address(user_ip)
        print(f'{ip} is correct. Version: IPv{ip.version}')
    except ValueError:
        print('Adress is invalid')
```

## Output:

```
Generating code
Finished generating code
192.168.1.1 is correct. Version: IPv4
```

## Final:

You have to import `pyximport` module and run `pyximport.install()` method before importing any `*.pyx` module. After running these two commands, you should have an imported module, just like a regular `*.py` file.