# Importing .c, .cpp, .hpp, .pyx modules in __init__.py file

Tags: python, github, importerror

I am trying to run GitHub code, where facing issues with importing files having extention .c, .cpp, .hpp, .pyx in **init**.py file.

Here's the file in which we have to import **bbox**, **cython_nms** and **gpu_nms** modules:

[image: Figure.1]

These are residing in the same folder as ****init**.py** is:

[image]

But it gives this err:

[image]

Holding two questions:

1. How to import other then .py extention modules in .py file?
2. Importing two or more modules having same name but different extensions using one `import` statement.

For instance:

`from . import bbox`

where two modules named with *bbox* in the same folder **bbox.c** and **bbox.pyx**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import function from .pyx file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508803/how-do-i-import-function-from-pyx-file-in-python)

Comment: @Mox Thanks, however I have to import `from . import bbox` where there are two modules with **bbox** having different extention **.c** and **.pyx** in the same folder, in the link you shared its specific to .pyx extention and infact its not working.

Comment: You can't import C code directly.  You have to compile the C code to a python extension.

Comment: The C code is not a module in the sense that you seem to be imagining.

Comment: @Miles Budnet, Thanks. I have to try this.